# Regex to capture only first line

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a weird string being returned and I need to find a regex to only return the first line, "Next Business Day" or something that I use to replace the everything after the first like that I can replace with an empty string.

I have something like this

```
$('#my-text').match(/(.|\n)/)
```

but this is capturing every line. Any advice?

This is the input string:

```
 Next Business Day 






                     -  $20.00 


                    Delivery next business day (except holidays). Order must be placed by 12:00 PM ET. Signature required.
```

Comment: Try: `.match(/(.*)/)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/vB1aP3/1)

```
$('#my-text').text().match(/(.+)/)
```

1. `$('#my-text')` returns jQuery object, string methods like `match` cannot be used on object. To get innerText of the element use `text()`.
2. To match only first line use `.+` or `.*`. Here `.` matches any character that is not newline.

Note: To get the matched result use `[1]` on the returned array by match.

Comment: Hmm I wasn't far off either :)